# Error when am calling Procedure of MySql in Jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have written some code calling the mysql procedure in jdbc

```
Driver requires declaration of procedure to either contain a '\nbegin' or '\n' to follow argument declaration, or SELECT privilege on mysql.proc to parse column types.
```

am getting above error when i call procedure below is the code:

```
CallableStatement  proc;

        if (JDBCConnection.connection != null) {
        Connection con = JDBCConnection.getConnection();
        System.out.println("in DAOimpl "+username);


        proc= con.prepareCall("{call getChildList(?) }");
        System.out.println("prosedure"+proc);

        proc.setString(1,username);
        System.out.println(proc);
        ResultSet rs=proc.executeQuery();
}
```

please give me the solution it is help ful for me.

Comment: What is it about the error message you find unclear?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear:

> Driver requires declaration of procedure to either contain a '\nbegin' or '\n' to follow argument declaration, or SELECT privilege on mysql.proc to parse column types.

So that tells us:

1. Your stored procedure declaration doesn't contain `\nbegin` or doesn't have an `\n` after the argument(s) declaration; or
2. The user you're using to call the statement doesn't have `SELECT` privilege on the stored procedure.

So step 1 is to figure out which of those two things it is.

To fix #1, put the body of the sproc in `begin` and `end`. So for instance, if your sproc is currently (altering an example from the MySQL docs a bit):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc(IN inputParam VARCHAR(255))
    SELECT CONCAT('zyxw', inputParam);
```

Change it to

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc(IN inputParam VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('zyxw', inputParam);
END
```

To fix #2, grant the `SELECT` privilege on the sproc to the user.